# Slice(...) is an invalid key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanna slice my df_d_train which has only one column (int) and a date as an index by 21 steps.

My df looks like:

```
df_d_train.head()

Close Date   
2011-12-31  4.472624 
2012-01-01  4.680778
2012-01-02  5.000000 
2012-01-03  5.145917 
2012-01-04  5.22872
```

I've tried:

```
step=21
x_train=[]
y_train=[]

    for i in range(step,df_d_train.shape[0]):
        x_train.append(df_d_train[i-step:i,0])
        y_train.append(df_d_train[i,0])

    x_train,y_train=np.array(x_train),np.array(y_train)
    x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1) #reshaped for RNN
    print("x_train shape= ",x_train.shape)
    print("y_train shape= ",y_train.shape)
```

...which raises:

> TypeError: '(slice(0, 21, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You should read up on pandas indexing. In this case you need .iloc  as in df.iloc[i,j].

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the exception was thrown by `x_train.append(df_d_train[i-step:i,0])`.

Actually the problem is in `df_d_train[i-step:i,0]`.

The problem is that:

- the index in *df_d_train* (*Close Date*) is either of *string* (*object*)
  or *datetime* type (you didn't specify this detail),
- but you attempt to pass **integers** as index values.

Another problem is that *0* is not a valid column name (at least looking at
your data sample).

I think, you dont't care about the index, but rather want to retrieve some
part of this DataFrame using **integer** numbers of rows / columns.

To do it, use *iloc*:

```
df_d_train.iloc[i-step:i,0]
```

The same in the next instruction.

And one correction to your post: The only column in your DataFrame is
not *int*. It is *float*.